# How can I use a appended button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, addeventlistener

I initially load into my page a table via "load".

```
$("#adresscontainer").load("/shop_stammdaten_get_adressliste.php", function() {
```

Within this function which is triggered by a click on a button which open a dialog form.
Initially this works fine.

```
 $(".create-user").on("click", function(e) {
```

This form will create a new entry in the table. I add this entry via APPEND to the table. Button the new entry has also a button to edit the line.

```
$( "#inneradressbox" ).append("<div id='inneradressbox'><button CLASS='create-user' id='TestID'>Bearbeiten</button></div>");
```

But if I click now on the new added button it this trigger not JQUERY not anymore.

I guess the reason is that the new button is not added to the EventListener. But I have no idea how I can add this now to this. I heared about BIND and ON but where in my append line should I do this? O rmust I change the structure of my code totally?

Hopefully somebody can help me?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: Attach the event listener to a parent element: `$(document).on('click', '.create-user', function(e) {`

Comment: @Andy: Thanks for this. It's exactly what I looking for. I just tried it on the wrong place. Thanks. You saved my Sunday.

Comment: @couganet See [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)